# Show occurrence of strings and append cell with percentage

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Trying to work out a way to auto update a Google Sheets with the percentages of a string occurrence and append the cell with that percentage.

```
foo | bar  | foo | bar   |
dog | cat  | bar | green |
dog | bar  | red | blue  |
car | bike | car | red   |

foo 50% | bar 25%  | foo 50% | bar 25%    |
dog 50% | cat 100% | bar 25% | green 100% |
dog 50% | bar 25%  | red 50% | blue 100%  |
car 50% | bike     | car 50% | red 50%    |
```

Not sure what the best approach is to append the cell or if this is even possible.

Comment: Do you want to append the cells that are already created with the percentage? Or do you want to create a new array with the appended percentages? If you are looking to customize what is already there, you will have to write a script.

Answer (score 0):

If your data array starts in A1, please create a new array with:

```
=A1&" "&text(1/countif($A$1:$D$4,A1),"0%")
```

copied across and down to suit.

(Returns `bike 100%` etc.)